# What is the difference between mutable and immutable managed object model in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

After reading `RestKit` docs about [RKManagedObjectStore](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectStore.html) I was confused about `createPersistentStoreCoordinator` method because there is a next warning in the description of this method:

```
**Warning:** Creating the persistent store coordinator will
render the managed object model    immutable. Attempts to 
use functionality that requires  a mutable managed object model 
after the persistent store coordinator has been created
will raise an application error.
```

I didn't understant what does it mean `immutable` managed object model? I can't found any information about this topic neither in official `Core Data` docs nor accross the Internet. Can someone give me an explanation of the difference between `mutable` and `immutable` managed object models? Why does creating of persistent store coordinator renders immutable managed object model? And what functionality requires a mutable managed object model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change a NSManagedObjectModel (add entities and attributes for example) in code, it is said to be mutable. But once you attach your object model to an persistent store coordinator you are not allowed to change it anymore - it has become immutable.

This also is described in the documentation for [NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Editing Models Programmatically Managed object models are editable
>   until they are used by an object graph manager (a managed object
>   context or a persistent store coordinator). This allows you to create
>   or modify them dynamically. However, once a model is being used, it
>   must not be changed. This is enforced at runtime—when the object
>   manager first fetches data using a model, the whole of that model
>   becomes uneditable. Any attempt to mutate a model or any of its
>   sub-objects after that point causes an exception to be thrown. If you
>   need to modify a model that is in use, create a copy, modify the copy,
>   and then discard the objects with the old model.

Comment: As I understood by editing model it is assumed - changing object graph?